# Getting an error using Backbone.js DELETE with ASP.Net MVC. Everything else works though.

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am able to successfully call Backbone's HTTP POST and PUT methods and have them link up to my server using Asp.Net MVC.

The problem is that when I call the HTTP DELETE using model.destroy() I get this error...

**The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Delete(Int32)' in 'GSASF.Controllers.AdminController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters**

Right before I call model.destroy() I logged the id to the console and it was correct. This is my code. *Note that my model doesn't have a field called id but instead a field called HoverId. The database table already existed so I have to make due.

```
 Delete: function(id) {
                if (id) {
                    for (var i = this.collection.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        var item = this.collection.at(i);
                        if (item.get("HoverId") == id)
                            alert("Item to be destroyed ID: " + item.get("id")); 
                            item.destroy();
                    };
          }

        [ActionName("SpaceToolTipEdit")]
        [HttpDelete]
        public ActionResult Delete(int id)
        {
            var imageHover = sr.GetImageHoverById(id);

            if (imageHover != null)
            {
                sr.DeleteImageHover(imageHover);
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
            }

            return new EmptyResult();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I feel dumb now.

The solution was all to simple. I had originally set the url attribute to my /{Controller}/{SpaceToolTipEdit} url. I was supposed to set this to the urlRoot attribute instead.